# Boost.MultiArray. В пространстве имен отсутствует член extents

Tags: c++

Добрый день. Помогите решить проблему. Когда использую член extents, VS его просто не видит и пишет, что такого нету в пространстве имен. Смотрел в документации, такой член есть, да и в примерах он используется. Как это исправить? Пытался подключить другие версии библиотеки, но проблема не решилась.

```
#include <boost_1_66_0\boost\multi_array.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    boost::multi_array<double, 1, allocator<double>> a{ boost::extents[6] };
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Пути к инклюдам следует прописывать до папки `boost` и инлюдить соответственно `#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>`

Answer (score 0):

Внутри заголовочных файлов `boost` использование зависимостей сделано через

```
#include <boost/path/to/header.hpp>
```

Заметьте, что в Вашем случае это не заработает, так как в настройках проекта указана не явно папка с `boost`, а чуть выше уровнем. Замените свой `some_path` в настройках сборки на `some_path/boost_1_66_0` и в исходнике уберите упоминание `boost_1_66_0\` - заработает